# XeroAPI - Get Invoice shared link

Tags: xero-api

I am not able to see the shared Invoice URL anywhere in the API response. Is there any additional scope to be added so I can receive the URL?

[image]

It's not included in the API response.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found it:

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices#onlineinvoice

You need to append the `/OnlineInvoice` to the basic call like this:

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/cb5119d0-9759-49d3-800b-7d0a90818178/OnlineInvoice
```